# Unable to hide TabBar on sub view in iphone

Tags: iphone

My app flow requires Navigation and TabBar controller. So I decided to use TabBar template. Since my first page is login which do not require TabBar, I used *presentModelViewController* to show Login screen which have Navigation bar if user Navigate to Forgot password.

```
LoginView *rootView = [[[LoginView alloc] init] autorelease];
navigationController= [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootView] autorelease];

[tabBarController presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:FALSE];
```

Ones the user login I dismiss view controller and show TabBar with 5 Tab and Each Tab contain TabaleView. User select any row and navigate to sub view.

The issue is, on sub view I dont need tab bar. (TabBar is needed ONLY on dashboard). If I hide tabBar a white space remain there. Is there any workaround to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On subview write this mehthod:

Subview.m:

- (BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed{
  return TRUE;
  }

and in Subview.h

- (BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed;

thats it, it has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this method when you are pushing the viewController of your subview.

```
[viewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: and where exactly I need to write this, On second screen where user tab on row Or on viewdid load of sub view?

Comment: just before you push the view controller, this is the easiest and simplest answer.

Comment: @iPhoneDev see the comment of Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

Put this method into your subview, where do you want hide the tababr.

Try this one.

```
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

     if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
    // Custom initialization
   }
     self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
     return self;
    }
```

Best of Luck.